# Java res folder not found error

Tags: java

I'm getting that error whilst using cmd to run my jar file, which I compiled using JarSplice.

The code it's on about is:

```
 shaderReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/res/shaders/" + fileName));
```

My file structure is:
[image: File Structure]

How can I get the thing to run?

Comment: Can you share with us the full command you used to run your JAR file?

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I managed to solve it: shaderReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Shader.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/shaders/" + fileName)));